# Python: HTTP Server and command execution

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to control a device on my RS232 port and i want to use a website for this purpose.
Python can create a small webserver and an HTTP page which shows the status of the device and some extra information.
If i need to change something on the RS232 device i also want to use the webpage (POST values).
What is the right way of making such an application?

I have python 2.7 at my disposal on debian.

Comment: There are plenty of [web frameworks for Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks). Any one should suffice.

Comment: I was thinking a little bit more basic then a whole framework, i only have maybe 20 commands i can send to the rs232 device.

Answer (score 0):

For your needs a minimal library like http://webob.org/ would be ideal. You only have to do something like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    do_stuff(req.POST.get['var1'])
return 'Status: %s' % get_status()
```

It is available in Debian: http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/python/python-webob

Comment: How do i incorperate this into the BaseHTTPServer module?

Comment: @HyperDevil You can use [`wsgiref.simple_server`](http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref.simple_server) like in the WebOb examples.